# Optimal way of picking a random number that's not in a container with C++

Tags: c++, random, stl, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have a container such as a `std::vector<int>` containing unique values. I'd like to pick a random integer number between `0` and a certain maximum `MAX`, that is not in the container. I'm concerned with the time complexity of such a program so I'd like to find something somewhat optimal.

So far I have basically two ideas that have both pros and cons. I can take a random number between `0` and `MAX`, and check if this number appears inside my container. If it is in the container, then try again.

```cpp
// Values I don't want to get are stored in Vec
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribution(0,MAX);
bool found = false;
int number;
while(!found) {
    number = distribution(generator);
    found = true;
    for(auto it : Vec) {
        if(it == number) {
            found = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

That solution is pretty simple, but it will be excessively slow when most values inbetween `0` and `MAX` are already in `Vec`, and my program might come across this edge case.

The other solution would be to first sort `Vec`, and then pick a random number between `0` and `MAX-Vec.size()`. That way, the random number refers to a specific number not in the vector, and I'd have to iterate through the sorted container to recover the actual value, like this :

```cpp
// Values I don't want to get are stored in Vec
std::sort(Vec.begin(),Vec.end());
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribution(0,MAX-Vec.size());
int ref = distribution(generator);
int shift = 0;
int result;
for(auto it : Vec) {
    if(ref + shift >= it)
        shift++;
    else {
        result = ref + shift;
        break;
    }
}
```

The main disadvantage of this way of doing things, while always taking the same amount of time, is that it requires to sort the container first, which might be costly. So far, if I'm not mistaken, the first method's best case should be O(n) while the second method is O(n log(n)) since it requires a sort.

My guess is therefore to check which method should be the most efficient depending on the size of the container compared to the maximum `MAX`, which would basically come down to : if the container is too large, then the probability to have to guess multiple values is too high, therefore use the second method. Is there another way to make this more optimal, or am I on the right way ?

Comment: `std::set` is a better container for this use-case.

Comment: Is `MAX` too big to do something along the lines of a Knuth shuffle: Make a `vector` of all of the possible values EXCEPT those in the verboten list, shuffle it, and pick the first item in the `vector`?

Comment: @user4581301 Instead of shuffling the list you can just pick the number from a randomly chosen index.

Comment: Yeah, I overcomplicated that. We're not trying to pick multiple unique values from the random sequence, are we?

Comment: Mind you, that leads to the question of what circumstances place a number in `vec`? If it's "We've already seen that number," shuffle could be exactly the right solution.

Comment: If you want a good solution, you'll have to move the "set of excluded elements" from being input to your algorithm to being a part of a data structure you use.  Otherwise, just reading the set of excluded elements is O(n), so you cannot beat that.

Comment: Why not simply generate another container that has all the values between `0` and `MAX` that are NOT in your container.  Then all you need to do is shuffle it, and then pick a value from that container.   As long as the original container doesn't change, the second container doesn't need to change (other than being shuffled) either.   If a value is added to (or removed from) your first container, you can also remove it from (add it to) the second container.

Comment: Using a container containing all the possible values was something I considered too, forgot about it in my answer. In my first thought it would be too expensive, but after reading your comments and giving it a second thought, it might be fine. Using an `std::set` container instead, and filling it with n possible values would be O(n log(n)) which is pretty much the same as my second solution, but wouldn't need any iterations after. The values already seen are removed from `vec`, but new values might be added afterwards, which would probably make the shuffle less optimal.